# Can I insert a website inside another with iframe?

Tags: iframe, proxy, x-frame-options

I am trying to insert a website into mine, but when I do it the server blocks it with x-frame header.

I tried to use a bypass (https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-frame-bypass) but it didn't work.

Is it possible to make an iframe from another website on mine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.